# Importing tcomb lib in Angular 2 / webpack app gives undefined

Tags: javascript, tcomb

Importing `tcomb` gives undefined:

```
import t from 'tcomb';
console.log(t); // undefined

// So this won't work
t.assert(t.Number.is(colorString), 'colorString is invalid argument');
```

However I got it working like this, which actually I like more:

```
import {assert, Number} from 'tcomb';
assert(Number.is(colorString), 'colorString is invalid argument');
```

Importing all as t returns just the `assert()` method not the full object

```
import * as t from 'tcomb';
```

I'm using a pretty standard setup with webpack-dev-server, angular 2, typescript and HMR. All libs so far load ok. The project is already a few months old.

Any idea on what is happening here? Why `t` is `undefined`?

Note: I'm using runtime check even if I have TS types all over the place because some services methods could still receive the wrong arguments at runtime. As a sidenote, `tcomb` seems fine to me, but just to learn, is there a better option than `tcomb`?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `var t = require('tcomb')`?
Perhaps something to do with the es6 import statement which is not working?

Comment: `require` works but, I was looking to use the `import` statement